# Iframe open page links in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, browser, iframe

I just need one thing. How to make "iframe page" to open their links in new tab.

I try to add `target="_blank"` but I think that is not iframe attribute.

My code open one webcam site. I want, when someone click on "sign up" to be opened in new tab...

Comment: wouldn't you use an anchor tag to open a link in a new tab? <a href="mylink" target="_blank">click me</a>

Comment: Forcing links to open in a new tab is a bad practice, it goes against what the user expects from a link (instead of redirecting the page, the browser throws him away to a different page). If a user wanted to open your link in a new tab, he would middle-click it, or choose "Open in a new tab" from the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to either have `target="_blank"` bound to specific links, or if you control the page that you're loading in the iframe, making sure that page has a `<base target="_blank">` element on it, which makes *all* `a` elements link through a new tab/window

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `target="_blank"`? It works no matter where the link is.

Comment: <IFRAME src="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto">Browser not compatible</IFRAME>

In this case Iframe will open google.com and when u click on "Images" I want to be opened in new tab

Comment: Oh, right. So you don't have control over the iframe contents. Well, nothing you can do there.

Comment: can you put target="_blank" inside the links that are inside the iframe?

Answer (score -1):

do you mean " links that are in a page that is loaded in a iframe" ?

if so , I'm not sure such a thing exists in html 4 . it depends on browser I think . firefox , chrome , opera open _blank in new tab  but IE opens it in new window

Comment: but where should I add  target="_blank"? I already try in Iframe

maybe to add javascript - onclick open that iframe link in new tab

Comment: I know how to make links open in new tab on click. I want to open in new tab, links that are on site loaded in Iframe - Exemple is pixhost - they advertise livejasmin... and when someone click on singup it opens link in new page